# Qt, WIndows and OpenSSL - Cannot Call Unresolved Function xyz

Tags: qt, openssl, arcgis

I've recently installed the ArcGIS Runtime SDK on my Windows 10 machine running Qt 5.9.1. When attempting to build a simple `QWidget` application using one of the ArcGIS templates, I get the following errors:

```
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSLv23_client_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_CTX_new
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_library_init
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function ERR_get_error
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function ERR_get_error
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSLv23_client_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_CTX_new
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_library_init
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function ERR_get_error
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function ERR_get_error
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSLv23_client_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_CTX_new
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_library_init
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function ERR_get_error
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function ERR_get_error
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSLv23_client_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_CTX_new
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_library_init
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function ERR_get_error
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function ERR_get_error
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSLv23_client_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_CTX_new
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_library_init
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function ERR_get_error
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function ERR_get_error
```

This problem seems to be quite common-place however most of the Google results come up with answers for Linux systems.

I have done the following:

- Downloaded and installed OpenSSL (from GnuWin32 OpenSSL)
- Copied across the `libeay32.dll` and `libssl32.dll` to the build folder
- Added the include path into the Qt pro file
- Verified that `network` is in the `QT +=` config section of the pro file

Yet none of the above has made any difference. I'm running MSVC 2015 32-bit kit.

Answer (score 1):

you have to add static libraries to your project.

Find out `libeay32.lib` and  `libssl32.lib` and add them to your project.

Refer

http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-qmake-libraries.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you need such two dll files:libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll.I use the same version qt as you do,so you can download them from [here](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Binaries) or directly get the zip from [here](https://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/Archive/openssl-1.0.2j-i386-win32.zip) (which works for me).

Different version openssl lib used by Qt,so you should test it in you code using static function below if you are not sure about it:

```
QSslSocket::sslLibraryBuildVersionString();
```

Comment: Why would you download a crucial library from some shady third-party site?

Answer (score 0):

If somebody else comes across this question, notice that since version 1.1.0 OpenSSL have changed their library names from:

- `libeay32.dll` -> `libcrypto.dll`
- `ssleay32.dll` -> `libssl.dll`

So you will need to include those two files with your project in order for QSsl functions to work.